# Exchange resource mailbox rule

Tags: exchange, rules

I have a resource mailbox set up in Exchange 2010 with auto attendant and it is auto accepting meetings without a problem. What I'm looking for it to do is the following:

- If a meeting is approved send out an approval email.
- If a meeting is cancelled by the creator send out a cancellation email.

If this were a users mailbox I'd just add the rules through Outlook on all incoming mail.

Is this possible with a resource mailbox? If so, can someone please let me know how?

Comment: Just to confirm, is this Exchange 2010 with the calendar attendant or another version of Exchange with a third party product?

Comment: Yes we are running Exchange 2010 with calendar attendant.

Answer (score 1):

Did you find the right answer and were you able to configure it already?

To my knowledge this behavior is by design, taking into account that the Resource Booking Attendant is configured, active and working